# upload image node.js express

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to upload image to server in node.js and express.

My jade image upload form:

```
include layout
div.container
    h2 Image Upload Form
    form#fileUpload(method="post" action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data") 
        label(for="payload") Select a file to upload:     
        input#payload(type="file" name="myFile" accept="image/*") 
        br 
        button#upload Upload
```

And in my `index.js` where I handle response and show form are:

```
router.get('/imageUpload', function(req, res, next){
    res.render('imageUpload', { title: 'Image upload form' });
});

router.post("/upload", function(req, res, next){ 
    console.log(req.files);
});
```

I am getting `undefined` error when I try to get `req.files`; I'm new to node so plz help.
Thank you.

Comment: Whats means `req.files`?

Comment: i find this on some blog so implement but this is not working i also try req.body but get empty result.

Comment: It's not exists in the docs: http://expressjs.com/api.html#req

Answer (score 3):

Finally image uploading is thanx Lucas Costa for help know i share my code

Step 1. Install **formidable** from official site [formidable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable)

Run command on your prompt

```
npm install formidable@latest
```

Step 2. My image upload form in **.jade**

```
include layout
    div.container
        h2 Image Upload Form
        form#fileUpload(method="post" action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data") 
            label(for="payload") Select a file to upload:     
            input#payload(type="file" name="myFile" accept="image/*") 
            br 
            button#upload Upload
```

Step 3. Add module in your file in my case i have **index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var util = require("util"); 
var fs = require("fs");
var formidable = require('formidable');
var path = require('path');

/* GET home page. */

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express', dataGet: "data" });
});

router.get('/about', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'C' });
});

router.get('/imageUpload', function(req, res, next){
    res.render('imageUpload', { title: 'Image upload form' });
});

router.post("/upload", function(req, res, next){ 
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
        // `file` is the name of the <input> field of type `file`
        console.log(files);
        res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
        res.write('received upload:\n\n');
        res.end(util.inspect({fields: fields, files: files}));
    });
    form.on('error', function(err) {
        console.error(err);
    });
    form.on('progress', function(bytesReceived, bytesExpected) {
        var percent_complete = (bytesReceived / bytesExpected) * 100;
        console.log(percent_complete.toFixed(2));
    });
    form.on('end', function(fields, files) {
        /* Temporary location of our uploaded file */
        var temp_path = this.openedFiles[0].path;
        /* The file name of the uploaded file */
        var file_name = this.openedFiles[0].name;
        /* Location where we want to copy the uploaded file */
        var new_location = 'F:/node/expressApp/myAppExpress/public/images/';

        fs.readFile(temp_path, function(err, data) {
            fs.writeFile(new_location + file_name, data, function(err) {
                fs.unlink(temp_path, function(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.error(err);
                        } else {
                        console.log("success!");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });
});

router.get('/:username', function(req, res) {
    // make somethings with username
    var username = req.params.username;
    console.log("get username"+ username);
});

module.exports = router;
```

All done! Hope this will help some one :-)

Answer (score 1):

The `undefined` is getting because doesn't exists `req.files`.

Alter to:

`console.log(req.body) // or req.body.myFile to get information of the input`

For upload image, I suggest you use [formidable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable-upload), somelike [this](http://inversekarma.in/technology/howto/uploading-files-in-nodejs-express-4-using-formidable/).

Comment: i try console.log(req.body)  but get empty result.

Comment: I had problems with it too (empty result), I can only get the file data through formidable.